# Why does PHP continues to run after a 413 error?

Tags: php, apache

I am testing my website to see the different kinds of error pages generated under various scenarios. In one of the scenarios, I tested uploading image files that exceed the total size allowed in `LimitRequestBody`. Sure enough, a `413 HTTP error` is produced with the following message:

> ### Request Entity Too Large
>
> The requested resource
>  /upload
>  does not allow request data
>   with POST requests, or the amount of data provided in the request
>   exceeds the capacity limit.

However, I was surprised that the upload form is still being generated below the error message. I was expecting Apache to stop PHP from processing the script. Is this the correct behaviour? Also, in the server access log, I am seeing a `200 OK` status code instead of a 413 error. Why is that so?

I understand that setting `post_max_size` in php.ini to be the same value may be able to trigger a PHP error and stop it from processing, but am I wrong to expect Apache to communicate this to PHP?

Answer (score 0):

The scripts stops when the Apache server throws a 500 Internal Server error. But otherwise, in most cases the script keeps on going (of course it depends on how you write it, you could catch this 413 scenario into a block of code and do not permit the script to execute after the server catches this error)

Comment: If what you wrote is true, then the original script would still run if there is a server redirection. Doesn't make sense.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow, it does continue after a reply with `Location: <new URL>`. In most cases, your PHP code calls exit() after that output.